# Spring contract-first REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger

I have a *Spring* web application - which doesn't use Spring-based GUI, but *Wicket* - and I would like to build *contract-first* REST services.

I already have a contract defined in *Swagger* and I generate model and API artifacts. Swagger *codegen* generates either *Spring Boot* artifacts, or *Spring MVC* ones.

My intention is to use ideally just a model, and maybe API (controllers) from this generated code. But up to my knowledge/research, there is no simple way to have just simple REST service without MVC/Boot boilerplate.

Therefore my questions are:

1. Is it possible to build *lightweight* Spring-based REST service, without having "heavy" dependency of full Spring MVC/Spring Boot?
2. If not, which approach is more *lightweight*? Spring Boot, or Spring MVC?

Comment: This is a question of opinion, and is therefore off-topic on StackOverflow. That said, it's super easy to [create a RESTful webservice with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

Comment: You are right, I'm going to re-formulate the question. I would rather avoid to use Spring Boot.

Comment: When you use Spring Boot, you are also using Spring Web MVC - in my opinion there's not a lot of difference between using Spring Boot or a plain old Spring webapp, you're not gaining a lot by not using Spring Boot. Also, why do you think this is "heavyweight"?

Comment: By heavyweight, I mean the difference between a lean application and boilerplate libraries, or transitive dependencies which I don't need for any functionality, but still packed in the application. E.g. difference between _MVC_ and _Boot_ is: 12 vs. 28 libraries and 6 vs. 9 MB of WAR archive.

Comment: @VítKotačka maybe look into JLink for the packaging? I believe it should cut down on unused modules and create a custom JRE just for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are misinterpreting the Spring ecosystem.

Spring MVC is THE rest web and web service library within Spring portfolio.
The same way as Spring-WS is THE soap web service library.
They are very similar in architecture and style of use.
The fact that Spring MVC is bundled with Spring Framework does not change the situation.

Spring Boot does not bring any new REST offering. It is just a bootstrap mechanism to start Java web server with web app already deployed from a plain `main()` method. Therefore if you see "Building REST web services with Spring Boot", it just means that it is Spring MVC bootstrapped by Spring Boot.

Therefore, the question to what is more lightweight is straightforward: Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question #2:

The usage of *Spring MVC* is more lighweight, then usage of *Spring Boot*:

Size of the WAR archive:

- 6,1 MB for *Spring MVC*
- 9,2 MB for *Spring Boot*

Number of libraries in WAR archive:

- 12 for *Spring MVC*
- 28 for *Spring Boot*